# Disable time picker from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Currently I'm using html [time picker](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time), but wouldn't mind using Javascript/Jquery/Ajax instead. The problem I'm trying to solve is this:

you are a customer, you ordered x from an employee. that x has a duration (start_time - end_time). The time form data is saved in `$customer_time`. Note that I had to store  the days as varchar. but my issue is not with date, it's with time.

The sql query I have is this (feel free to make it better if you could)

```
SELECT employee_id, product_start_time, product_end_time, date FROM orders
WHERE NOT (
      employee_id ='$employee_id'
  AND res_date = '$res_date'
  AND $customer_time =TIMEDIFF ('product_start_time','product_end_time')

)
```

I guess I wrote timediff right, if not please correct it as I have never used it before, the idea is

`$customer_time = start_time - end_time`

Anyhow, if the employee is free, then the customer can proceed with the reservation, otherwise, the time_ picker field should be disabled. I need a time picker like the html one, but one that I can work with and disable the time. I don't want a time picker where I select default time from a list of intervals.

So please

- Check if my mysql query is correct
- Recommend a time picker
- An example implantation is highly appreciated

**Update**

Perhaps a better version of my query is to use INTERVAL instead of timediff, since every product has a duration in minutes, few have durations in hours, but mostly minutes.

My initial idea was to create a time field that keeps checking for availability, like you check for available usernames, in a username field using ajax, don't know if that would work though.

Comment: i want a time picker input field which can have disabled values. so if user x selected a time, user y cant select the same time
but not dropdown select list, i want an input field

Comment: the rest of my question is discussing my sql query

Comment: please note that i would give the accepted answer at least 50 rep if he implements a solution or help with sql, thats why my question seems broad, might give bounties to more than one user, depending on the answer coz this question is extremely important to me

Comment: and i wrote the entire sql so it wont take you a minute just verifying if it's correct, therefore it's a single not two questions in 1, but if you still feel that i cheated by asking 2 questions in 1, then just tell me how to make the time picker input field have a disabled option

Comment: So is the user supposed to select both the start time and the end time? Or is there a start time and a duration to select? You write that the time form data is saved in `$customer_time`, and since you want a time picker I am bit puzzled why you then say `$customer_time = start_time - end_time`, because that is not a time, but an interval. Can you clarify?

Comment: @trincot say product x takes 45min, the user picks the reservation time, which is `start_time` and `end_time` is calculated, in other words, end_time = reservation_time + product_duration. yes it's an interval indeed. but the idea, is that the user input a reservation_time he wishes to have in a time field, we calculate the interval backend, if his reservation time conflicts with someone else, we tell him to pick another time. so we check to see if the `duration of selected product + time selected by user is in orders database,` the query could be better but its just prototyping for now

Comment: Hi, @Lynob,  i know it is not the answer to your question but you ask also for recommendation for time picker.  I want to recommend you a plugin a clock picker it is very  cool and works like a charm very easy to use : https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/

Comment: @GeorgePlamenovGeorgiev would have used it, if it accepts  an array of disable times or something

Comment: @Lynob i have a idea actually :) You can use the callback method and search in array with the disabled times you generate if it is not in there continue with your logic. See this for the callbacks :

https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/jquery.html

I'm talking about afterHourSelect, beforeDone, afterDone . Hope this will help.

Comment: @GeorgePlamenovGeorgiev can you implement your idea? I'll give you this bounty and another +50 (if SO let me give multiple bounties per question)

Comment: Hi @Lynob i will try to help you here is my thinking what i have suggest:

http://jsfiddle.net/yu4gaoo3/

Select 11:00, 12:00 or 13:00 to see that they are really busy right now :)

Comment: @GeorgePlamenovGeorgiev awesome!! can you post an answer so i could give you the bounty? it's expiring soon

Comment: I will added but I'm happier that i help :) I did not do it for the bounty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Lynob here is timepicker with disabled times. You need to put more time in the disabled array and it will work.

```
var input = $('#input-a');
var dissabledTime = ["11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00"];
input.clockpicker({
autoclose: true,
afterDone: function() {
   console.log(dissabledTime.indexOf($('#input-a').val()));
                       if(dissabledTime.indexOf($('#input-a').val()) != -1)
                         {
                           alert("My dear select other time i'm busy :)");
                           $('#input-a').val('');
                         }
                    },
});
```

Here is the whole [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu4gaoo3/)

Regards,

George

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from what you are trying to say :

Store selected dates to mysql in date format. While querying, check the selected dates per user or how you wish to do it. Then proceed in this way.

This will be per session. You have to store the results in an array :

```
 var disableddates = ["02-14-2015", "05-19-2013", "12-20-2014", "another one"];


function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
  }
```

You have to call the datepicker function later on.

```
    $(function() {
      $("#date").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
      });
   });



   <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Tite</title>
   </head>
    <body>
      <input id="date" type="text">
    </body>
    </html>
```

You have to include jquery datepicker plugin and dependencies.

Comment: my issue is not the date, it's the time. 
 
i want a time picker input field which can have disabled values. so if user x selected a time, user y cant select the same time but not dropdown select list, i want an input field

Comment: Input field as in? You want to show the timepicker like datepicker or an empty field where user can type the time manually? Because that will be bad for UI, since user has to know what and how to write the format if you don't give them option.

Comment: yes but could be like a popup that has the minutes and and he cant select a disabled range, for instance, i select 11 am and then i cant select 15 to 30 min coz someone else has reservation from 11 15 to 11 30